# Scanning a directory every 1 sec

Tags: .net

If I want to monitor a directory in a .net server application running as a service, when would you say that the interval between the scan is "un-healty" for the server?

I would like to scan the directory every 1 sec if I know the server can handle it well.

It is not an option of mine to use the file system watcher.

Your experience is much appreciated.

Update:
The directory that is scanned will not have any sub dirs.
The size of files is expected to be around 5kb to 500kb.

I would like to poll the directory when my application is ready to take on new data, so I don't think the file system watcher suits in this case.
An option would of course be to save information about the files that the FSW triggers in a "pending list".

Comment: Need more information. How big is the directory/sub-directories, what does a 'scan' involve, and why are file-system watcher utilities that are designed for the job not an option?

Comment: Also, consider using FileSystemWatcher class. Again, depending on the directory size,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Timers.Timer` to do this. Set its interval to 1000 as it accepts milliseconds, then set the `AutoReset` property to `true`. Probably it is appropriate to disable the timer during the scan, so if the scan takes longer than a second, it won't be initiated again (on another threadpool thread).

```
partial class AService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer CountDown = new Timer(1000);

    void CountDown_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CountDown.Enabled = false;
        ScanFolder("C:\\Temp");
        CountDown.Enabled = true;
    }

    void ScanFolder(string FolderPath)
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FolderPath);
        // Manipulate files ...
    }

    public AService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        CountDown.Elapsed += CountDown_Elapsed;
        CountDown.AutoReset = true;
        CountDown.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        CountDown.Stop();
        CountDown.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking in more terms of what negative effects a scan have to the server (I guess both to the OS and hardware) when I have a scan with a low interval.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, this certainly requires a test to be determined. But I don't expect any significant overheat - neither to OS nor the hardware. Listing a directory is a matter of referencing the MFT structure which isn't any big. Even if it is, there are OS mechanisms to cache these data, so if happens often it'll not bother the disk at all; just the memory.